# Watson Conversation making programmatic calls to client

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I have a node app that uses the Watson Conversation service. I am able to successfully trigger a call to another API via a dialogue node using the JSON that it uses for the reply. However after reading up it seems I am doing it wrong. I am triggering my client server to make a REST call by adding an action property to the context.

```
{
  "context": {
  "action": "lookup"
  },
  "output": {}
}
```

When I get my result I add it onto the context object and pass it back to the conversation service. This seems to work ok, but it causes some issues. 
1) having to manually delete these props after I trigger the thing I want
2) In conversation I must wait for user input even though I am not actually requesting user input on the front end but rather my client app is sending a message with no input text and the results of the REST call on the context object. This message which is returned to the conversation at the node where the action was triggered is what triggers the child nodes. It seems like there is a standardized way IBM wants you to make these programmatic calls regardless of if it's to an IBM cloud function, or your own client app. https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions
docs method:

```
{
  "context": {
    "variable_name" : "variable_value"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name":"<actionName>",
      "type":"client | server",
      "parameters": {
        "<parameter_name>":"<parameter_value>",
        "<parameter_name>":"<parameter_value>"
      },
      "result_variable": "<result_variable_name>",
      "credentials": "<reference_to_credentials>"
    }
  ],
  "output": {
    "text": "response text"
  }
}
```

Is this a new feature? I was referencing sample projects for my own app and I didn't see this pattern. By using this format will it tell the parent node to wait for a response to come back before trying to process the children? Will it prevent me from needing to delete properties off the context object so that I'm not calling the same action over and over with the same parameters in further turns of the conversation?

Comment: It's a new feature: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0A6X-KNoB8

Comment: I actually did see this video. In this example I believe they're calling an IBM cloud function directly from the conversation service. In my app all Conv. messages go through a proxy server which then makes a request to the 3rd party API. My question specifically is if using this formatting in the JSON and including an "actions" property will change the way the Conv. service behaves. Or, if I do it like I show in my first snippet above that is effectively the same.